# Facebook comments URL unreachable - URL follow failed

Tags: facebook, url, comments

My facebook comments are hidden behind an email entry page. Once you enter your email, then the page shows the comment box. You can see them here: http://anyluckyday.com -- once you enter a promotion, the comments will be displayed. The error I keep getting on all my pages is:

```
Errors That Must Be Fixed:

URL Follow Failed: There was an error in fetching the object at URL 'http://anyluckyday.com/promo/21/lookmatic-eyeglasses', or one of the the URLs specified via a redirect or the 'og:url' property including one of http://anyluckday.com/promo/21/lookmatic eyeglasses.

Circular Redirect: Circular redirect path detected (see Redirect Path section for details).

Error Scraping Redirect: Bad Response Code (redirect)
```

Here is what I'm using for the meta properties to redirect to the proper urls and pull the info:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="webpage"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://anyluckday.com<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://anyluckyday.com/uploads/<?=$img[3]['path']?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="AnyLuckyDay - <?=$data['title']?>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="AnyLuckyDay - <?=$data['title']?>"/>
```

Any idea why I'm getting these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the linter (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fanyluckyday.com%2Fpromo%2F21%2Flookmatic-eyeglasses) and there's some errors that must be fixed.  Start with the redirect your website is using that is causing the circular reference.  I think facebook would like to get a 200 response and not the redirect that you currently sent it.

```
URL Follow Failed:  There was an error in fetching the object at URL 'http://anyluckyday.com/promo/21/lookmatic-eyeglasses', or one of the the URLs specified via a redirect or the 'og:url' property including one of http://anyluckday.com/promo/21/lookmatic-eyeglasses.
Circular Redirect:  Circular redirect path detected (see Redirect Path section for details).
Error Scraping Redirect:    Bad Response Code (redirect)
```